# Error during spark submiting job on Yarn cluster from remote host

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, kerberos, spark-submit

I try to spark-submit my jar with Spark application to remote Yarn Cluster.

I downloaded files from cluster:

```
hdfs-site.xml
yarn-site.xml
core-site.xml
```

Set environment variable HADOOP_CONF_DIR on directory with these files.

Than I do spark-sumbit:

```
set HADOOP_CONF_DIR=C:\projects\config\0

spark-submit ^
    --deploy-mode cluster ^
    --principal test@tdomain ^
    --keytab "test.keytab" ^
    --queue garliq ^
    --properties-file "SparkSubmit.conf" ^
    --class ru.rosbank.App ^
    scala-spark-maven-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

But I get error:

> INFO ConfiguredRMFailoverProxyProvider: Failing over to rm1 Exception
> in thread "main" java.io.IOException: DestHost:destPort
> node1.tdomain:8032 , LocalHost:localPort
> RS-AAA11111111/11.23.111.164:0. Failed on local exception:
> java.io.IOException: Couldn't set up IO streams:
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Server has invalid Kerberos
> principal: rm/node1.tdomain@DOMAIN, expecting: rm/11.22.33.155@TDOMAIN
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
> at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:831)
> at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:806)
> at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1515)
> at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1457)
> at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1367)
> at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:228)
> at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:116)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.getClusterMetrics(Unknown Source)
> at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.getClusterMetrics(ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.java:271)
> at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:422)
> at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:165)
> at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:157)
> at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
> at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:359)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.getClusterMetrics(Unknown Source)
> at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.getYarnClusterMetrics(YarnClientImpl.java:605)
> at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.$anonfun$submitApplication$1(Client.scala:179)
> at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging.logInfo(Logging.scala:57)
> at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging.logInfo$(Logging.scala:56)
> at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.logInfo(Client.scala:65)
> at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:179)
> at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1227)
> at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnClusterApplication.start(Client.scala:1634)
> at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:951)
> at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
> at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
> at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
> at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1030)
> at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1039)
> at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala) Caused by: java.io.IOException: Couldn't set up IO streams:
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Server has invalid Kerberos
> principal: rm/node1.tdomain@DOMAIN, expecting: rm/11.22.33.155@TDOMAIN
> at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:866)
> at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$3700(Client.java:411)
> at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1572)
> at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1403)
> ... 29 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Server has invalid Kerberos principal: rm/node1.tdomain@DOMAIN,
> expecting: rm/11.22.33.155@TDOMAIN
> at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.getServerPrincipal(SaslRpcClient.java:337)
> at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.createSaslClient(SaslRpcClient.java:234)
> at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.selectSaslClient(SaslRpcClient.java:160)
> at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.saslConnect(SaslRpcClient.java:390)
> at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupSaslConnection(Client.java:617)
> at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2300(Client.java:411)
> at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:804)
> at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:800)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
> at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
> at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:800)
> ... 32 more

Problem is here:

> Server has invalid Kerberos principal: rm/node1.**tdomain**@**DOMAIN**, expecting: rm/11.22.33.155@**TDOMAIN**

As you can see, Domain on test cluster has value DOMAIN, but have to be TDOMAIN.

Where can I find settings of SErver principal rm/node1.tdomain@DOMAIN? Is it somewhere on cluster? or I have to do additional settings on my local host for launching spark-submit?

Comment: Can kinit be performed with the Kerberos Domain using the keytab on the spark remote host? I have faced this issue when the Kerberos server was not reachable by my VM that had the spark-client installed.

Answer (score 0):

You could look through this deployment steps doc from [cloudera](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.5/developing-spark-applications/content/running_spark_streaming_jobs_on_a_kerberos-enabled_cluster.html). You can ignore the spark streaming bit.

You need to pass the keytab files in the —files option so that it may be copied onto the remote spark machine that would then use it to authenticate with the Kerberos server using your principal/service account, if it is reachable.